# Power Bi Embedded Javascript api getVisuals

Tags: powerbi-embedded

```
let reportContainer = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('reportContainer');
this.report = this.powerbi.load(reportContainer, this.config);
let reportObject = <pbi.Report>this.report;
this.report.on("loaded", (result) => {
  console.log("loaded");
  reportObject.getPages().then(result => {
    console.log("sucessfully got pages");
    this.pages = result;
    result.forEach(element => {
      var page = <pbi.Page>element;
      console.log("A Page:" + page.displayName);
      page.getVisuals().then(visualSucessResult => {
        console.log("get Visuals sucess");
        visualSucessResult.forEach(aVisualElement => {
          var aVisual = <pbi.VisualDescriptor>aVisualElement;
          console.log("aVisual.name:" + aVisual.name);
        });
      }, visualFailureResult => {
          console.log("Get Visual Failed");
        })
    });
  }, error => {
    console.log("Error getting Pages");
  })
});
```

I am trying to load a report and get Pages for the report and then get Visuals for each page. 
When I get Visuals , its failing to get Visuals. It seems as if the report visuals doesn't contains some properties which code is trying to get, but I couldn't find anything wrong in the report. I have spent few hours now, it seems like some silly mistake which I am not able to figure out.
I am writing this in angular 5

```
reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:632 TypeError: Cannot read property 'entities' of undefined
at Function.t.getDisplayNameForSQAggregate (powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at t.visitColumnAggr (powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at o (powerbiportal.dependencies.bundle.min.js:22)
at Object.n [as visit] (powerbiportal.dependencies.bundle.min.js:22)
at r.getOriginalDisplayName (powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at r.getDisplayName (powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at r.populateDisplayNamesByDataRole (powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at r.getRawTitleComponents (powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at r.getTitleText (powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at reportembed.bundle.min.js:21


TypeError: Cannot read property 'findProperty' of undefined
at Function.t.getDisplayNameForProperty(powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at t.visitColumn (powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at a (powerbiportal.dependencies.bundle.min.js:22)
at Object.n [as visit] (powerbiportal.dependencies.bundle.min.js:22)
at r.getOriginalDisplayName (powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at r.getDisplayName (powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at r.populateDisplayNamesByDataRole (powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at r.getRawTitleComponents (powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at r.getTitleText (powerbiportal.explore.bundle.min.js:12)
at reportembed.bundle.min.js:21
```

Comment: Ok. after few more attempts, I found that, if I try to get visuals before report is rendered, we have this issue. Once I render the report, then getVisuals is working fine. But I don't want to render the report to start with as I want to show some and hide some visuals .

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a limitation of GetVisuals API. I added this to Wiki page and I will post here once this limitation is removed.

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Get-Visuals#limitations